# Shorter notation for interval type

Tags: postgresql, time, format, intervals, postgresql-8.4

How to convert interval like `1 day 14:28:09.00901` to shorter form:
`1 day 14:28:09`? 
So, What's needed is to remove digits after dot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [date_trunc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC)():

```
SELECT date_trunc('second', interval '1 day 14:28:09.00901');
```